# Visual Studio Snippet Declaration broken

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

Using Visual Studio 2013 Express, I thought I'd try creating a snippet that declares and instantiates a new object.

It should look like this (with the default *Object* and *val*, and the cursor at the specified place:

```
Object val = new Object(<cursor_here>);
```

But my snippet does not work; it does not display the default values *Object* and *val*. It looks like this:

```
= new (<cursor_here>);
```

...and I have to manually enter the Type (twice) and variable name.

What did I do wrong? Here is the snippet XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Declare New</Title>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnyppetType>Expansion</SnyppetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>

        <Snippet>
            <Literal Editable="true">
                <ID>thing</ID>
                <Default>Object</Default>
            </Literal>

            <Literal Editable="true">
                <ID>name</ID>
                <Default>val</Default>
            </Literal>


            <Code Language="CSharp" Kind="method body">
                <![CDATA[$thing$ $name$ = new $thing$($end$)]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```